# Integration of $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\pi(x+i\xi)^2} dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently reading stein and shakarchi complex analysis, and he does an integration of:
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\pi(x+i\xi)^2} dx$. Let $A$ be a rectangle with four vertices located at $(r,0), (r,i\xi), (-r,i\xi), (-r,0)$. For conveniennce, assume that $\xi>0$. He does a contour integration of $e^{-\pi z^2}$ over $\partial A$, and I am confused when he integrates over the line segment $[(r,i\xi), (-r,i\xi)]$:

$\int_{r}^{-r} e^{-\pi(x+i\xi)^2} dx = e^{\pi \xi^2}\int_{r}^{-r} e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi i x\xi} dx =_{(*)} 
-e^{\pi \xi^2}\int_{-r}^{r} e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi x\xi i} dx$.

How does (*) makes sense? I tried change of variable $x \mapsto -x$, but it only gives me an integration:
$-e^{\pi \xi^2}\int_{-r}^{r} e^{-\pi x^2}e^{2\pi i x\xi} dx$.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\int_{-r}^r e^{-\pi x^2} \, e^{\pm 2 \pi i x \xi} \, dx = \int_{-r}^r e^{-\pi x^2} \, \cos ( 2\pi x \xi) \, dx \,\,\, \pm \int_{-r}^r e^{-\pi x^2} \, \sin (2\pi x \xi) \, dx.
\end{align}
The second term on the r.h.s vanishes as the integrand is odd, and therefore the two integrals on the l.h.s give the same result.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I came up with my own answer, and does it work? Let $\gamma$ be a line segment [(r,iξ),(−r,iξ)]. Then, $\int_\gamma f = -\int_{-\gamma} f$, where $-\gamma$ is curve traversing $\gamma$ in opposite direction. Then, $-\int_{-\gamma} f dz= -\int_{-r}^r e^{-\pi (x+i\xi)^2} dx = -e^{\pi \xi^2} \int_{-r}^r e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx$, and $\int_{\gamma} f dz  = e^{\pi \xi^2} \int_{r}^{-r} e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx$. Hence, $-e^{\pi \xi^2} \int_{-r}^r e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx = e^{\pi \xi^2} \int_{r}^{-r} e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx$

Comment: @JamesChung ‌I don't see how the last equation would solve your issue?